# Intent Chrome browser from lockscreen dont work

Tags: android, google-chrome

It's a same problem: [Android Google Chrome not firing after lockscreen app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835750/android-google-chrome-not-firing-after-lockscreen-app)
But this problem doesn't succeed. I can't reslove it.

I can use

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

and all works. But need waiting 5000 sec :(

I this its bug in Google Chrome for Android.

Comment: Hello, interesting you mention this, but wouldn't it make more sense to move this 'question' to the original question and write it as an 'answer' instead ?

Comment: This is a known bug in Android core framework, you need to wait 5 sec for all apps you try to start.

Comment: JonasCz but activity start normally! Why chrome cant start? Any other browser works fine.
Werner Van Belle original question about lockscreen app. And die 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think this is a bug in Chrome. However I found a workaround [Android lock screen notification is not able to open Browser on double tapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285006/android-lock-screen-notification-is-not-able-to-open-browser-on-double-tapping)

Let me know if this works for you or not.